# How do I disable/hide adaptive cards/action buttons without using redux middleware?

Tags: adaptive-cards, bot-framework-composer

I'm building chatbot leveraging Bot Framework Composer(C# bot). According to the specifications, we created a react-app and integrated bot into it with the help of a DirectLine token. We want to disable the card/action button from WebChat after the adaptive card is rendered, so the user cannot click on the action button again. Is there a way to disable or hide the adaptive card after a single use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the following class to all the buttons which are loaded in adaptive cards which are under li element for each message:

> .ac-actionSet .ac-pushButton

You have to do some logic in javascript or react based on this class and hide previous li elements buttons except current li element.